# Proving this modulo question

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Let a,b be integers and p is prime

> $a^pb^{p^2} \equiv 0\pmod p \Rightarrow a \equiv 0\pmod p$ or $b \equiv 0\pmod p$

and using elemination method

> $a^pb^{p^2} \equiv 0\pmod p$ and $a \not\equiv 0\pmod p \Rightarrow b \equiv 0\pmod p$

from here
since $a \not\equiv 0\pmod p \Rightarrow p \nmid a \Rightarrow gcd(a,p) = 1$

by Fermat's little theorem we get

> $a^p \equiv a\pmod p$

so,

> $ab^{p^2} \equiv 0\pmod p$

again since $ p \nmid a$

so

> $p \mid b^{p^2}$

I'm pretty sure $p \mid b^{p^2} \Rightarrow p \mid b$ is wrong

I can't seem to find a way to make it so that $p \mid b$ to get 
$b \equiv 0\pmod p$

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ If a prime divides a product then it divides some factor, so $\,p\mid a\cdots a b\cdots b\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z/p$ is a field so $a^pb^{p^2}=0$ mod $p$ implies that $a^p=0$ mod $p$ or $b^{p^2}=0$ mod $p$.

If $a^p=0$ $mod$ $p$, Little fermat implies that $a^p=a$ mod $p$ done.

If $b^{p^2}=0$ mod $p$, you have $b^{p^2}=(b^p)^p=b$ mod $p$ by little fermat.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how $b^{p^2} = (b^p)^p \equiv b\pmod p$ I always get confused with powers of powers

Comment: Oh did you mean $(b^p)^p \equiv b^p \pmod p \equiv b \pmod p$ by applying little fermat twice?

Comment: yes, I mean that